# How to make a colorbar with image in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, figure, colorbar

I have three subplots with images inside it. I want to make a colorbar to the right of each subplot. How to make a custom color range (0-10) and then plot it aside of the subplot?

This is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
import numpy as np

image1 = image.read('a.jpg')
image2 = image.read('b.jpg')
image3 = image.read('c.jpg')
#Define Subplots
fig1, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(20,4))

#Axis 1
ax1.imshow(image1, extent=(60, 70, 23.5, 25.0), cmap='reds', zorder=-1, aspect='auto')
ax1.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax1.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax1.colorbar()




#Axis 2
ax2.imshow(image2, extent=(60, 70, 23.5, 25.0), cmap='reds', zorder=-1, aspect='auto')
ax2.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.colorbar()

#Axis 3
ax3.imshow(image3, extent=(60, 70, 23.5, 25.0), cmap='reds', zorder=-1, aspect='auto')
ax3.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax3.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax3.colorbar()



plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,3) 
plt.show()
```

But this shows error. Kindly help me.

I want something like this but for all the axis
[image]

Thanking in anticipation

Comment: You write *"But this shows error"*, but don't tell which error, nor on what line. Preferrably you copy the full error trace (as text) into the post.  See [this colorbar tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colorbar_basics.html) about how, when there are multiple subplots, the colorbar needs to know for which element a colorbar is needed. Something like `img1 = ax1.imshow(image1, ...)` and then `plt.colorbar(img1, ax=ax1)`.

Comment: Colorbar is a figure method not an axes method.  Please do fig1.colorbar()